# Apache Rewrite Rule not working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Some rules are working properly, and everything is properly set up in the conf files to allow rewrites to work correctly.
But some rules are failing or may be the URL string does not reach that rule and is already redirected.

Like for this rule:

```
RewriteRule coach/(.*)$ coach.php?coach=$1
```

If I call the URL `localhost/coach/fitness` it gets redirected to `localhost/coach.php` and no GET param is received in the PHP file.

Now if I change this rule to

```
RewriteRule coach/(.*)$ cp.php?coach=$1
```

and also change the file name from `coach.php` in my dir to `cp.php`
then it works perfectly fine for the given URL and the GET param is received.

So the problem is if the file with URL string name exists it gets redirected to that file only and no redirection rules are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule coach/(.*)/?$ coach.php?coach=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It's important to note that mod_negotiation (ie. MultiViews) processes the URL _before_ mod_rewrite.